# Calculate distance in kilometers between two points

Tags: shapefile, r, distance

I have a few questions regarding the calculation of the distance between 2 postal codes.
Take a look at the following code.

```
###
# load the different packages we need
###

require("rgdal")
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")
require("rgeos")

###
# load the shape file
###

belgium = readOGR(dsn="XXX", layer="NAME")
belgium.points = fortify(belgium, region="POSTCODE") 
head(belgium.points)
tail(belgium.points)
```

This gives ;

```
      long      lat     id
1 151584.6 175068.7    1000
2 150829.0 174739.9    1000
3 150614.4 174580.1    1000
4 150178.8 174208.4    1000
5 149715.7 173823.0    1000
6 149126.5 173269.7    1000

      long      lat    id
51839 83871.46 215487.5 9992
51840 84519.46 215217.5 9992
51841 83925.51 214823.3 9992
51842 83578.20 214704.9 9992
51843 82796.53 215022.7 9992
51844 81811.86 214716.5 9992
```

What I now want to do is calculating the distance between the centroid of each postal code. The postal code is given by the variable id in the dataset belgium.points. **Is the code below valid? Can I convert it to kilometers?** (Please if you need additional info just ask me.

```
lat = sapply(split(belgium.points, belgium.points$id), function(x) mean(x$lat))/1000
long = sapply(split(belgium.points, belgium.points$id), function(x) mean(x$long))/1000
lat.dist = outer(lat,lat,function(lat1,lat2) (lat1-lat2)^2)
long.dist = outer(long,long,function(long1,long2) (long1-long2)^2)
spatial.dist = lat.dist + long.dist
```

Comment: Have you tried to use this function: http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/sp/html/spDistsN1.html ?
It should help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lat = sapply(split(belgium.points, belgium.points$id), function(x) mean(x$lat))/1000
```

...
You sure this gives you a correct latitude value? If you know the initial projection, then why not convert it into a spatialpointdataframe and use `spproject` with a lat-long projection to get the actual values.

**To calculate distances:**

1. Ether use the `PointDistance` tool in the `raster` package. It even works with non-latlon point locations
2. Otherwise use this custom R function to approximate the distance

   ```
   # Calculate distance in kilometers between two points
   earth.dist <- function (long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
   {
   rad <- pi/180
   a1 <- lat1 * rad
   a2 <- long1 * rad
   b1 <- lat2 * rad
   b2 <- long2 * rad
   dlon <- b2 - a2
   dlat <- b1 - a1
   a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
   c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
   R <- 6378.145
   d <- R * c
   return(d)
   }
   ```

Comment: I used that particular function to calculate the centroid of my postcode areas. For my application it don't has to be a very exact result.

Comment: I found out that the latitude/longitude values were in fact not expressed in degrees but in meters. I noticed that the difference in 1 degree longitude was more or less 111200 meters. The difference in latitude was 70000 à 74000 meters (dependent on the longitude). I'll mark you answer as correct though, because it answers the original question in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

Use `gCentroid` from [rgeos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) to calculate centroids.
Use spDists from [sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html) (as mentioned by @Jot eN above) to calculate distance matrices.

I made up a simple example using admin boundaries. Note that the parameters of `spDists` change, depending on your map units. The example is for degrees. If you have meters use something like: `spDists(centroids)/1000`

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

# getting sample data of the three main Belgian regions
tmpdir <- tempdir()
download.file("http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.zip", "world.zip")
unzip("world.zip", exdir = tmpdir )
shapefile <- paste0(tmpdir,"/ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp")
world <- readOGR(shapefile, "ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits")
unlink(tmpdir)
belgium <- world[world$ADM0_A3 == "BEL", ]

centroids <- gCentroid(belgium, byid=TRUE)
spDists(centroids, longlat=TRUE)  #distance in km
```